# Removing [' and '] from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have several GB of CSV files where values in one of the columns look like this:

[image: URL in brackets]

Which is a consequence of this:

```
urls.append(re.findall(r'http\S+', hashtags_rem))
...
merger = {'Content': clean, 'AttrURL': urls}
cleandf = pd.DataFrame(merger)
...
df.insert(3, "AssocURL", cleandf['AttrURL'])
```

It took me a while to generate these files and, looking back, I'd certainly write this part differently, but doing it again is a very time-consuming and simply unnecessary endeavour.

Is there another efficient way to remove [' and '] from this column using pandas or csv?

Comment: Have you tried something like `df['AssocURL'] = df['AssocURL'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)[0])`

Comment: If you have several GB of data to process, the chosen solution with `apply` is almost certainly not efficient...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to remove the squared parentheses. It should be something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda string: string[2:-2])
```

Comment: I think OP needs to remove 2 chars at the beginning and 2 at the end.

Comment: It did the job, but for some reason it also removed everything else except for columns 1 and 3(?) -- seems strange to me.

Comment: sorry, there was an error in my code that caused this. It is all good now. I went with your solution, and also learned about lambda. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Not a very attractive answer, but how about just with .str.replace ?

```
df['AssocURL'].str.replace("\'","").str.replace("[","").str.replace("]","")
```

Comment: Can't upvote at the moment, but thanks a lot. Even though I still went with the lambda solution, I believe this one would work just as well. Initially, I tried to use str.replace, but there was another error in my code and that's why it didn't work -- and it was not str.replace's fault after all.

Answer (score 4):

From the question it's unclear if the column is a string or if it contains elements which are themselves a list which contains a single string. `re.findall` returns the second option. If it is the second option eg.,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AssocURL': [['link1'], ['link2']]})
#   AssocURL
# 0  [link1]
# 1  [link2]
```

You can use `explode`:

```
df['AssocURL'] = df['AssocURL'].explode()
#   AssocURL
# 0    link1
# 1    link2
```

Comment: I should've been more explicit about this -- totally forgot to mention that it's a string. Thanks for pointing it out and proposing both solutions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Super simple,
just do:

```
df['AssocURL'].replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
```